# Pandas condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
Country/Region  Lat      Long
Afghanistan     33.00    65.00
Andorra         42.5063  1.5218
Albania         41.1522  20.1633
```

This is my dataset I want to create a new column with the following condition if Lat < 37 and > -37 return 0

```
df.loc[df.Lat < 37 and df.Lat > -37, 'newcol'] = 0
```

This is the code I'm trying to use for the condition but I am receiving a Value error

Comment: Replace `df.Lat < 37 and df.Lat > -37` with `df.Lat.between(-37,37, inclusive=False)` or `df.Lat.abs() < 37`.

Comment: change and to bitwise `&` and wrap each condition in parenthsis - `df.loc[(df.Lat < 37 )& (df.Lat > -37), 'newcol'] = 0`

Comment: In general, don't use `and`, do use `&` and wrap the series: `(df.Lat < 37) & (df.Lat > - 37)`.

Comment: or use `np.where` - `df['new_col'] = np.where((df.Lat < 37 )& (df.Lat > -37),0,np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
df.loc[(df.Lat < 37) & (df.Lat > - 37), 'newcol'] = 0
```

I think the `&` and the `|` act as AND and OR in pandas.